# How to add an object class to a list of object mapped with @DBRef MongoDB spring Data 3.4.12

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have a problem with a REST API that I am testing in postman. I want to be able to authorize a list of student objects to an object of type "Curso" through MONGODB Spring Data document entities. but when I do the aggregation it tells me that the List attribute is null and I can't add values:

```
@Document
public class Student {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Getter @Setter
    private String primer_nombre;
    @Getter @Setter
    private String segundo_nombre;
    @Getter @Setter
    private String primer_apellido;
    @Getter @Setter
    private String segundo_apellido;
    @Getter @Setter
    private String numero_documento;
    @Getter @Setter
    private documentType tipo_documento;
    @Getter @Setter
    private int nota;
    @Getter @Setter
    private String estado;

    public void calificarEstudiante(){
        if(this.getNota() < 3){
            this.setEstado("reprobado");
        }else{
            this.setEstado("aprobado");
        }
    }
}

@Data
@Document
public class Curso {
   @Id
   @Getter @Setter
   private String id;
   @Getter @Setter
   private String nombre_curso;
   @Getter @Setter
   private String descripcion;
   @Getter @Setter
   private String maestro;
   @DBRef
   @Field("estudiantes")
   public List<Student> estudiantes;

   public void addStudentsInCourse(Student student){
      System.out.println("estudiantes = " + estudiantes); //students is null
      this.estudiantes.add(student);
   }
 }
//Contoller
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/endpoints")
public class QualificationsController {
   @PutMapping("/inscribir/{studentID}/in/{cursoID}")
   public Curso agregarEstudianteACurso(
        @PathVariable(value ="studentID")
        String studentID,
        @PathVariable(value ="cursoID")
        String cursoID)
   {
 
        Curso currentCurso = cursosServices.findById(cursoID);
        Student currentStudent = studentsServices.findById(studentID);
        currentCurso.addStudentsInCourse(currentStudent);
        return this.cursosServices.save(currentCurso);
   }
}
```

How can I add the list of students to the "Curso" object and then persist the changes made? When annotating an attribute with @DBRef I don't have access to the persisted elements of the student object?

Comment: Is class `Cuourse` a typo?

Comment: Yes, the name of my classes is in Spanish, I have translated it into English. But it's the same class

Comment: I corrected the semantic error

Comment: Does the data exists into DB? If it not exists maybe that's why is not initializing the list. If data exists the list should not be null or empty but if not exists and is not initialized I guess is null.